# Simple broadcast library/example in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, broadcast

I'm putting together a client/server application written in C/C++. It is mostly C with some C++ features - I come from the C and Java world and don't use lots of heavy advanced C++ language features. In any case, the server resides on one computer and does a variety of internal calculation, and several times a day (at unpredictable times) it will broadcast information to some number of clients (residing on other computers) that have registered with the server to listen for such broadcast messages. The server must be able to broadcast to all registered clients with 100% reliability and very quickly so that clients can update their own internal data to reflect the state change in the server - the state change that the server just broadcast to them. Since it must be reliable, it would have to be TCP/IP, not UDP.

This seems like a pretty standard architecture for networking in C++, but I'd like to find a good library that would allow me to do this easily (some sort of wrapper for the WinSock library so that I can do it easily on Windows without having to dig in to the specific quirks of WinSock) and a simple example of how one would do this sort of thing.

Thanks.

Comment: please change the tag broadcast to multicast - its not applicable to the question

Answer (score 2):

Check out `boost::asio`. Their examples are available here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

It abstracts most platform-specific quirks so you can get down to business quickly.

Comment: I used asio in production a lot and this is really great library. You only must remember to include it only in files where you need it and only parts that you need - asio adds a lot to compilation time (in my system +2s for every cpp file that uses it).

Comment: Boost has way too much overhead and much too steep a learning curve. I'm looking for something more lightweight. And perhaps I need a higher level protocol than TCP to ensure reliability? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two libraries for C/C++ network communications from free and open-source world that rock - [LibEvent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent) and [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Using them you won't need to dig into specifics of the operating system, or specific APIs for network communications. They both have a good documentation and a set of decent [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

As a side note, even using TCP/IP doesn't make the communication protocol reliable from the higher point of view. In order to provide reliability, applications usually define higher-level protocols on top of TCP/IP. Those protocols describe sequencing of the messages, heartbeats, retransmission support etcetera. There are also reliable protocols built on top of UDP (so-called RUDP).

If you feel like speed and reliability is very important, you may want to use one of the industry leading technologies, such as Tibco, LBM (Informatica/29West), or [Tervela](http://www.tervela.com/). All of those solutions can work on top of different communication protocols while providing seamless API for the user.

Comment: You raise a good point on reliability. I'm happy to use a very high level protocol that ensures reliability - e.g. if the socket is dropped at some point (because nothing is happening for several hours) I'd like it to automatically reconnect/handle the issue for me. What high level protocol would you suggest and what Windows library implements this?

Comment: The only free/open-source vendor that I know of is ZeroC Ice (zeroc.com). Their solution is a bit different from pure messaging, it is more like CORBA. They do support automatic connection re-establishment (in fact, they don't keep it alive if you don't use it, but that can be turned off optionally), and they are reliable unless you use one-way invocations.

Comment: ZeroC Ice looks interesting but it is GPL. I'm looking for something without GPL restrictions. Thanks for the help though, now I know more than when I started. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will require a decent amount of C++ features (templates, etc) but [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is excellent and exactly what you need for this task.  However, it'll clearly require some getting used to, as the programming model is quite different from straight C++.  There is pretty good documentation and lots of examples at the site.

Comment: I hear the boost overhead is huge and the learning curve is steep. I'm hoping for something other than Boost.

Comment: The boost overhead and learning curve are both very reasonable. The benefit of using boost far outweighs the cost.